# require one directive controller in another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

These are the ways i tried to require one directive's controller in another one.

1) http://jsfiddle.net/Xarm2/1/

2) http://jsfiddle.net/82UKq/1/

In both the cases you can see in the firebug console, that the required directive's controller is either `undefined` or an empty object.

1) How can i access 'd1Cntrl' inside the `d2` directive.

2)Please let me know one use case that will need me to require an directive controller in another directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. See this nifty screencast from John Lindquist on [directive to directive communication](http://egghead.io/video/angularjs-directive-to-directive-communication/)
2. For example, if you have an input element where you would like to apply two custom validations where one validation should only run if first validation passes (e.g. pattern matching validation should only activate if element has a value).

Answer (score 0):

Few thinks i could like to put it here

1) Directives are not creating their own scope, For ex.
    `<superhero strength>The Hulk</superhero>
    <superhero flight speed strength>Superman</superhero>
    <superhero speed>The Flash</superhero>`

these three directives will share the same scope, unless we explicitly say `scope:true` or `scope:{}` in the `superhero` definition. If you we are not creating new scope, then the last superhero will be in effect.

2) If we create a new scope at `superhero` level, that same scope is shared by the sibling directives like `strength`, `flight` etc..

3) If we require an directive controller inside another directive, the api that is defined on the directives controller using `this` keyword will be exposed to the requiring directive. Please note that the methods that are defined in the controller scope `$scope` wont be visible.

Please feel free to edit if the sentences making is wrong or the points were wrong.